# Destroy a gameobject while it's still changing its scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to destroy a prefab while it still changes it's scale but it gives me error 'the object of type boxcolider2d has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it'. Below is my code

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    StartCoroutine(ReScale(new Vector3(.5f, .5f), new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f), collision));
    Destroy(collision.gameObject,.5f);
}

private IEnumerator ReScale(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Collider2D gameObjectCollided)
{
    float progress = 0;

    while (progress <= 1 && gameObjectCollided.gameObject != null)
    {
        gameObjectCollided.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, progress);
        progress += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    gameObjectCollided.transform.localScale = to;

}
```

What should I add to my code?

Comment: why not just destroy the collision.gameobject at the end of the coroutine?

Answer (score 1):

You are still trying to access the GameObject in your IEnumerator after it has been destroyed:

```
gameObjectCollided.transform.localScale = to;
```

You can add a check to see whether the object still exists beforesetting the scale:

```
if(gameObjectCollided.gameObject != null) 
{
    gameObjectCollided.transform.localScale = to;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You start a Coroutine that operates on the object, and immediately destroy it. It makes very little sense. Basically what you are asking your game engine is “start changing the scale but wait the next frame, and destroy it on this very frame”. I suppose this is not what you really want to do.
My best bet is that what you want is “on collision, start shrinking the object and when you are finished shrinking it, destroy it”.
In this case, you need to move your `Destroy(collision.gameObject,.5f);` in the coroutine, as last instruction (I’d remove the delay):

```
private IEnumerator ReScale(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, Collider2D gameObjectCollided)
{
 float progress = 0;
 while (progress <= 1 && gameObjectCollided.gameObject != null)
    {
     gameObjectCollided.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(from, to, progress);
     progress += Time.deltaTime;
     yield return null;
    }
    gameObjectCollided.transform.localScale = to;
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
}
```

In case you need to stop the Coroutine before destroying the object:

```
private Coroutine reScaleCoroutine;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
     reScaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ReScale(new Vector3(.5f, .5f), new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f), collision));
    }

private void StopCoroutineMethod()
    {
     StopCoroutine(reScaleCoroutine);
    }
```